# Rowspan feature in react fixed data table

Tags: reactjs, fixed-data-table

Is there something like `rowspan` in fixed data table, so that I can merge  cells.

Or any other way to achieve a table like below

[image]

Given data is

```
data = [
     {
        name: "John",
        expenses:{
           q1: 20,
           q2: 30,
           q3: 30,
           q4: 20
        }
     },
     {
        name: "Jane",
        expenses: {
           q1: 10,
           q2: 10,
           q3: 10,
           q4: 10
        }
     }
]
```

Comment: `rowspan` is 100% okay in React